# gradle war: how to build jar, not classes

Tags: gradle, jar, war

Gradle war plugin: how to build a jar and add it to war?

```
projectRoot/
        src/main/java
        src/main/resources
        src/main/webapp
```

1. build a jar (foo.jar) from the java source code and resources.
2. add the jar under the WEB-INF/lib of the war.

   WEB-INF/lib/foo.jar

The war task will not build a jar by default, and add all java classes and resources under WEB-INF/classes.

### UPDATE

```
The War plugin extends the Java plugin to add support for assembling web
application WAR files. It disables the default JAR archive generation of the 
Java plugin and adds a default WAR archive task.
```

There is a way to enable the Jar generation and let task war depends on task jar?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you care?

Comment: You can split the project into two modules, one containing the classes and resources (use java plugin), the other the webapp (use war plugin) and depending on the first.

Comment: the jar can be used by others as a dependency. maybe two module is a solution. Can the war project be the root project, and the jar project as a sub-project? or two modules? what is difference between module and sub-project? thanks.

Comment: Module and subproject are the same.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if eastwater still needs the answer, hope others with the same problem will find this helpful

you can add/configure the war task in build.gradle

```
war {
    classpath = classpath - sourceSets.main.output
    from (jar) {
        into 'WEB-INF/lib'
    }
}
```

once build succeed, in build/libs folder you'll see the generated jar and the war containing the generated jar instead of classes

Comment: Looking for clarification: a war file created like this will have none of the project class files, and the project jar will be in the lib? So /classes can be empty? I think this responds to the 'why do you care' question asked by someone else. Is the answer "it's preference", that is, have .class files under /classes OR project .jar files under /lib (I'm not talking about dependencies). Is there a conflict if both the project .jar and .class files are present?

Answer (score 0):

Add those into your root build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

jar{
    String somestr=''
    configurations.runtime.each{somestr=somestr+" lib\\"+it.name}
    manifest{
        attributes 'Main-Class':'your_class_name'
        attributes 'Class-Path':somestr
    }
}

task copyJar(type:Copy){
    from configurations.runtime
    into ('build/libs/lib')
}

task release(type: Copy,dependsOn:[build,copyJar]){
}
```

add finally run this command
`gradle release`