# How to specify my own manifest file in the Gradle war plugin?

Tags: maven, gradle

How to specify my own manifest file in the Gradle war plugin? I need a one to one translation of the below maven pom snippets to Gradle. 
I wish there is a one to one translation tool from maven to grade. btw, the gradle init does not address the details such as exlcude, manifestFile.

from maven pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>validate</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/**</warSourceExcludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:manifest)  : you can customize the Jar/war `manifest` as follows (more details in the [Manifest API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/java/archives/Manifest.html) )

```
war{
    manifest {
        // include attributes from a custom manifest file
        from("src/main/resources/CUSTOM-MANIFEST.MF")

        // specify custom attributes
        attributes('My-Attribute': 'value')
    }
}
```

Note that Gradle will merge your custom attributes with the ones generated by the `war` task itself, if any.

Comment: I have the same question as this one , to let the war plug in build jar into web-inf\lib , not classes. do you know the answer?  [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748067/gradle-war-how-to-build-jar-not-classes)

Comment: oh. I did a vote up. didn't realize the green tick. just checked.